# Detect exiting route changes in Vue

Tags: vue.js, router

I'm working on a component which enables the user to undo the deletion of an item. However, the item should be deleted when the user navigates to another route. To achieve this I'm watching the route like so:

```
  `watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      if (this.showUndo === true) {
        console.log('item will be deleted');
        this.confirmDelete();
      }
    },
  },
```

`

Unfortunately, this gets only triggered when I enter this specific route and not on exiting it. An explanation why that is or an alternative to my     `watch:` - method would be much appreciated!

Basically I'm looking for an alternative to     `beforeRouteLeave` since this is a sub-component and therefore I can't use Navigation Guards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue lifecycle hook- **BeforeDestroy** is fired right before teardown. Your component will still be fully present and functional. If you need to cleanup events or reactive subscriptions,
beforeDestroy would probably be the time to do it.

```
<script>
export default {

  beforeDestroy() {
   //Try like this
    this.confirmDelete();
    console.log('item will be deleted');

  }
}
</script>
```

Ref - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy